# Scan SVN log for specific comments to generate release notes

Tags: svn

Is there any tool that will enable me to collect and filter all comments from SVN commit log up to the specified revision?

I'd like to be able to add comments like:

"API_CHANGE: some comment about API change."

"BUGFIX: issue 12345 is fixed."

and collect them automatically when I want to generate release notes.

Thanks.

Comment: What about `svn log` and `grep -C5` in a more sophisticated version?

Comment: Anything similar available on windows?